# how do I return data from controller to @include in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, include

I have a view called side.balde.php which is like a sidebar.
This side is called in to home and various other views using @include.

If i just return view side.balde.php with variables/data in my controller, then home view can't recognize the variables.

```
 return view('incs/side',compact('users','etc'));
```

I can return this data with home view and all the @includes in home view can inherit this data. but the problem is I'm using this @include in few other pages.

how do I forward data to side.balde.php so all views calling side.balde.php can access the data.

Comment: Take a look at [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers). (Not sure if `'incs/side'` works and `compact('users''etc')` is missing a comma)

Comment: I typed the code wrong, comma is not the problem. I don't understand the link you sent, it's too complex for me. I don't even have some of the files and folders mentioned in documentation like App\Repositories\UserRepository and app\Http\View\Composers. Can some one send a working example.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but you'll have a hard time developing if you can't adapt code examples to your specific needs. Sorry I can't be of more help, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 options to share data across multiple views:

1. App Service Provider (Short)
   Open your app service provider and in `boot` method write:

   $users = User::get();
   View::share('users', $users);
   Now all of your views will have access to that key `users`.
2. [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers) Please visit this link to understand how the view composer works.

You can get your work done with the first option though. Thanks.

Comment: i tried the first methods before, thought it wouldn't work. i get this error 'Call to a member function followings() on null' . followings() is a belongsToMany relation between user and followers table declared in user.php model. Any idea how i can make  followings() accessible in AppServiceProvider?

Comment: You can use `with` to get relations data. like `User::with('following')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

got it working with

```
public function boot()
    {

      View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        //code
        $view->with('users', $users);
        });

    }
```

and at top used `use App\User;` and `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`